# What would be time complexity of a binary search that makes call to another helper function?

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search

The helper retrieves value to be compared in the search function. here mem is an object.

```
def get_val(mem, c):    
  if c == "n":
    return mem.get_name()     
  elif c == "z":
    return mem.get_zip()
```

In the function below the helper function above is called in each iteration. Will this impact the time-complexity of the binary search or will it still be O(log n)

```
def bin_search(array, c, s): 
  first = 0
  last = len(array)-1
  found = False
  while( first<=last and not found):
    mid = (first + last)//2
    val = get_val(array[mid], criteria)
    if val == s:
      return array[mid]
    else:
      if s < val:
        last = mid - 1
      else:
        first = mid + 1 
  return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `get_val()` once per iteration of your binary search, the total time complexity should be

*O(log n * f(x))*,

where *f(x)* is the time complexity of `get_val()`. If this is constant (does not depend on the input, such as the contents of `array`), then indeed your total time complexity is still *O(log n)*.

Comment: get_val() does not recieve an array but an element of array and as such performs the same (constant) operation everytime, returnig a stored variable. So I think it is constant

Comment: @GunJack Yes, but I don't know what that element contains. It could be another array. If you know that it's constant, then it doesn't affect the time complexity so you have a regular binary search of O(log n).